# Topology Counterexample - Book Error?: Prove: Let f:(X, T) -> (Y, T*) be open and onto, and let B be a Base for T. Show f(B) is a base for T*

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, open-map

From Schaum's Topology Outline, Chapter 7, Supplementary problem #39.

Prove:  Let $f:(X,\mathscr{T})\rightarrow (Y, \mathscr{T*})$ be open and onto, and let $\mathscr{B}$ be a base for $\mathscr{T}$.  Then {$f [B]:B\in \mathscr{B}$} is a base for $\mathscr{T*}$.

I think this cannot be proved in general.  [Edit:  The book does not specify whether or not $f$ is continuous.  Other problems in the same section do occasionally say "Let $f$ be continuous", so I don't think we can assume continuity here.]

Here is what I believe is a counterexample.  Please let me know if I'm missing something:

Let $X = \{a,b,c,d\}$ and $\mathscr{T} = \{X, \{a,b\}, \{c,d\}, \emptyset\}$

Let $ Y = \{1,2,3\}$ and $\mathscr{T*} = \{Y, \{1,2\}, \{2,3\}, \{2\}, \emptyset\}$

Define the function,  $f:X\rightarrow Y,  f(a) = 1;  f(b) = f(c) = 2; f(d) = 3$

Then, $f$ is open because it maps open sets to open sets, and $f$ is onto because every element of $Y$ is mapped to.

Now, let $\mathscr{B} = \{\{a,b\},\{c,d\}\}$ be a base for $\mathscr{T}$.

This is base because its elements are open sets and every open set in $\mathscr{T}$ is a union of members of $\mathscr{B}$.  (NB: the empty union provides the empty set)

But then $\{f [B]:B\in \mathscr{B}\}=\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\}$, which is NOT a base for $\mathscr{T*}$ because you cannot obtain the open set $\{2\}$ with unions of elements of this set.

So the general statement of the proof is false.

Speculation:  Perhaps the problem should read "into" instead of "onto"?

Comment: Your $f$ is not continuous. I guess $f$ has to be continuous?

Comment: Good point, but there's nothing in the statement of the problem that says $f$ is continuous.  Other problems don't seem to assume that it is without saying so, i.e., other problems explicitly tell you "Let f be continous".  So since this one doesn't, I'm not assuming it.

Comment: If we assume $f$ is additionally continuous and $y \in U \subset Y$ is an open neighbourhood of $y$, then $V := f^{-1}(U)$ is open and there is a point $x \in V$ with $f(x) = y$. Because $\mathscr{B}$ is a basis there is $B \in \mathscr{B}$ with $x \in B \subset V$ open. Then $y = f(x) \in f(B) \subset f(V) = U$ is an open neighbourhood. So it seems to hold in this case.

Comment: Indeed if you only want open and onto you can simplify/generify your example: Let $X$ be a set and $\mathscr{T} = \{\emptyset, X\}$ be the indiscrete topology and $\mathscr{T}' = \mathscr{P}(X)$ be the discrete topology. Then $f \colon (X, \mathscr{T}) \to (X, \mathscr{T}'),\, x \mapsto x$ is bijective and open, but a counterexample if $|X| \geq 2$, whatever basis you choose on $(X, \mathscr{T})$. So the statement doesn't make a lot of sense without $f$ being continuous.

Comment: I see what you mean.  There are several small problems in the book that are trivial like this.  They may not make a lot of sense as stand-alone problems, but they really are helpful for concept mastery, i.e., recognizing basic ideas in basic situations.  

I think of it like when beginning algebra students stumble over adding zero or multiplying by one in disguised ways.  When you really know what you're doing, the trivial cases are obvious.  But for those who aren't there yet, extra examples of the same concept in slightly different wats do help illuminate how these basic elements work.